# How do you send_keys current date using Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

How do you pass today's date with send_keys in selenium?

```
input.send_keys(print(date.today()))
```

When I try this, it says None.

Comment: What do you mean it 'says' 'none'? It enters the letters N-o-n-e in the input? If so the problem isn't send keys, it's with what the print function is returning. Try logging the value returned by print(date.today())

Answer (score 0):

I kept playing with it, basically I came up with this:

```
d = datetime.date.fromordinal(datetime.date.today().toordinal()-7).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
date1.send_keys(d)
```